# How to read properties file inside jar?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have a config.properties file under the package com.abc.properties. From one of the java class present in com.abc.util, I need to read the property file. Both the files are present inside jar. 
I have tried using

```
fs = new FileInputstream(VerifyFolderStructure.class.getResourceAsStream("com/abc/properties/config.properties"));
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Please help.

P.S: VerifyFolderStructure is my java class from which I need to load the properties file.

Comment: Also I have tried fs = new FileInputstream(VerifyFolderStructure.class.getResourceAsStream("../properties/config.properties"));
this also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you getting some error? And, what do you mean by `VerifyFolderStructure is my java class from which I need to load the properties file.`

Comment: Well, you won't be able to use it as ` FileInputStream` for starters, because it's not a `File` if it's inside the `jar`.

Comment: Can you please suggest an alternative? I tried using InputStream as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To obtain the stream you don't need FileInputStream at all. You can get the properties' file stream like this

```
InputStream is = VerifyFolderStructure.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/abc/properties/config.properties");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add "/" in the front of you path.if you don't add "/" that means the properties is located in the same packages path as  VerifyFolderStructure class.

Comment: "/" in front of path means  load properties from the classpath.

Comment: I tried that also. After adding that I'm getting a FileNotFoundException. Otherwise I'm getting a NullPointerException

Comment: does VerifyFolderStructure in the same path of you file?

Comment: VerifyFolderStructure is under the package com.abc.util