# How to detect build time at runtime in Quarkus?

Tags: java, maven, build, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I am pretty new to Quarkus and I can't seem to find a way to obtain build information like build version or last built time at run time. Any insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to configure Maven to record that information in `application.properties`.
Something like: [How to access maven.build.timestamp for resource filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228472/how-to-access-maven-build-timestamp-for-resource-filtering).

Then at runtime you would read the properties and extract what you need. Likely something like [How to read properties file inside jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070109/how-to-read-properties-file-inside-jar/29070177)

Comment: I'm glad to hear it!