# logging.properties can not be found - where should it be?

Tags: java

Where should I place the `logging.properties` file to be available for the code?

```
LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(new FileInputStream("logging.properties"));
```

Curently there is a `IOException` because the file is not found.
This is my idea project structure. I tried to place it in `src` and in `src\main`.

[image]

Comment: Does the file exists at the location where you start your application from? Do you want to use `getResourceAsStream()` instead?

Comment: @Progman it's not a servlet based app, just a runnable jar

Comment: Then check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070109/how-to-read-properties-file-inside-jar or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815404/load-properties-file-in-jar

Comment: @Progman  I placed it in the folder where my jar file and it works but I want to keep it inside jar

Comment: The file should be in `src/main/resources`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2816029/139985